# Combine several NumPy "where" statements to one to improve performance

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I am trying to speed up a code that is using Numpy's [`where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function. There are two calls to `where()`, which return an array of indices for where the statement is evaluated as `True`, which are then compared for overlap with numpy's [`intersect1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) function, of which the length of the intersection is returned.

```py
import numpy as np

def find_match(x,y,z):

    A = np.where(x == z)
    B = np.where(y == z)
    #A = True
    #B = True
    
    return len(np.intersect1d(A,B))

N = np.power(10, 8)
M = 10

X = np.random.randint(M, size=N)
Y = np.random.randint(M, size=N)
Z = np.random.randint(M, size=N)

#print(X,Y,Z)
print(find_match(X,Y,Z))
```

Timing:

- This code takes about 8 seconds on my laptop. If I replace both the `np.where()` with `A=True` and `B=True`, then it takes about 5 seconds. If I replace only one of the  `np.where()` then it takes about 6 seconds.
- Scaling up, by switching to `N = np.power(10, 9)`, the code takes 87 seconds. Replacing both the `np.where()` statements results in the code takes 51 seconds. Replacing just one of the `np.where()` takes about 61 seconds.

How can I merge the two `np.where` statements that can speed up the code?

This is already an improved version of the code where the speed was increased ~4x by replacing a slower lookup with for-loops. Multiprocessing will be used at a higher level in this code, so I can't apply it also here.

For the record, the actual data are strings, so doing integer math won't be helpful.

---

Version info:

```
Python 3.9.1 (default, Jan  8 2021, 17:17:43) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)] on darwin
>>> import numpy
>>> print(numpy.__version__)
1.19.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```py
def find_match2(x, y, z):
    return len(np.nonzero(np.logical_and(x == z, y == z))[0])
```

Sample run:

```py
In [227]: print(find_match(X,Y,Z))
1000896

In [228]: print(find_match2(X,Y,Z))
1000896

In [229]: %timeit find_match(X,Y,Z)
2.37 s ± 70.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [230]: %timeit find_match2(X,Y,Z)
272 ms ± 9.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I've added `np.random.seed(210)` before creating the arrays for the sake of reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

Two versions that scale differently depending on size:

```
def find_match1(x,y,z):
    return (x==y).astype(int) @ (y==z).astype(int) #equality and summation in one step

def find_match2(x,y,z):
    out = np.zeros_like(x)
    np.equal(x, y, out = out, where = np.equal(y, z)) #only calculates x==y if y==z
    return out.sum()
```

Testing different data sizes:

```
N = np.power(10, 7)
...

%timeit find_match(X,Y,Z)
206 ms ± 12.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit find_match1(X,Y,Z)
70.7 ms ± 1.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit find_match2(X,Y,Z)
74.7 ms ± 3.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

N = np.power(10, 8)
...

%timeit find_match(X,Y,Z)
2.51 s ± 168 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit find_match1(X,Y,Z)
886 ms ± 154 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit find_match2(X,Y,Z)
776 ms ± 26.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

EDIT: since @Tonechas's is faster than both, here's a `numba` method:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def find_match_jit(x, y, z):
    out = 0
    for i, j, k in zip(x, y, z):
        if i == j and j == k:
            out += 1
    return out

find_match_jit(X,Y,Z)  #run it once to compile
Out[]: 1001426

%timeit find_match_jit(X,Y,Z) # N = 10**8
204 ms ± 13.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If threading is allowed:

```
@njit(parallel = True)
def find_match_jit_p(x, y, z):
    xy = x == y
    yz = y == z    
    return np.logical_and(xy, yz).sum()
        

find_match_jit_p(X,Y,Z)
Out[]: 1001426

%timeit find_match_jit_p(X,Y,Z)
84.6 ms ± 2.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```