# Python Multiprocessing (Splitting data in smaller chunks - multiple function arguments)

Tags: python-3.x, performance, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

---

Note from 22.02.21:
-Potentially my problem could also be solved by a more efficient memory usage instead of multiprocessing, since I realized that the memory load gets very high and might be a limiting factor here.

---

I'm trying to reduce the time that my script needs to run by making use of **multiprocessing**.
In the past I got some good tips about increasing the speed of the function itself ([Increase performance of np.where() loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65883951/increase-performance-of-np-where-loop)), but now I would like to make use of **all cores of a 32-core** workstation.
My function compares entries of two lists (X and Y) with a reference lists Q and Z. For every element in X/Y, it checks whether X[i] occurs somewhere in Q and whether Y[i] occurs in Z. If X[i] == Q[s] AND Y[i] == Z[s], it returns the index "s".
(Note: My real data consists of DNA sequencing reads and I need to map my reads to the reference.)

What I tried so far:

- **Splitting** my long lists X and Y into **even chunks** (n-chunks, where n == cpu_count)
- Trying the "**concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()**" to run the function for each "sublist" in parallel and in the end combine the result of each process to one final dictionary (matchdict). (--> see commented out section)

My problem:

- All cores are getting used when I uncomment the multiprocessing section but it ends up with an error (index out of range) which I could not yet resolve. (--> Tip: lower N to 1000 and you will immediately see the error without waiting forever)

Does anyone know how to solve this, or can suggest a better approach to use multiprocessing in my code?

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures

np.random.seed(1)

def matchdictfunc(index,x,y,q,z):  # function to match entries of X and Y to Q and Z and get index of Q/Z where their values match X/Y
    lookup = {}
    for i, (q, z) in enumerate(zip(Q, Z)):
        lookup.setdefault((q, z), []).append(i)

    matchlist = [lookup.get((x, y), []) for x, y in zip(X, Y)]
    matchdict = {}
    for ind, match in enumerate(matchlist):
        matchdict[index[ind]] = match
    
    return matchdict

def split(a, n):  # function to split list in n even parts
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    return list((a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n)))

def splitinput(index,X,Y,Q,Z):  # split large lists X and Y in n-even parts (n = cpu_count), make new list containing n-times Q and Z (to feed Q and Z for every process)
    cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    #create multiple chunks for X and Y and index:
    index_split = split(index,cpu_count)
    X_split = split(X,cpu_count)
    Y_split = split(Y,cpu_count)

    # create list with several times Q and Z since it needs to be same length as X_split etc:
    Q_mult = []  
    Z_mult = []
    for _ in range(cpu_count):
        Q_mult.append(Q)
        Z_mult.append(Z)
    return index_split,X_split,Y_split,Q_mult,Z_mult

# N will finally scale up to 10^9
N = 10000000
M = 300

index = [str(x) for x in list(range(N))]
X = np.random.randint(M, size=N)
Y = np.random.randint(M, size=N)

# Q and Z size is fixed at 120000
Q = np.random.randint(M, size=120000)
Z = np.random.randint(M, size=120000)

# convert int32 arrays to str64 arrays and then to list, to represent original data (which are strings and not numbers)
X = np.char.mod('%d', X).tolist()
Y = np.char.mod('%d', Y).tolist()
Q = np.char.mod('%d', Q).tolist()
Z = np.char.mod('%d', Z).tolist()

# single-core:
matchdict = matchdictfunc(index,X,Y,Q,Z)

# split lists to number of processors (cpu_count)
index_split,X_split,Y_split,Q_mult,Z_mult = splitinput(index,X,Y,Q,Z)  

## Multiprocessing attempt - FAILS! (index out of range)
# finallist = []
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
#         results = executor.map(matchlistfunc,X_split,Y_split,Q_mult,Z_mult)
#         for result in results:
#             finallist.append(result)
    
#         matchdict = {}
#         for d in finallist:
#             matchdict.update(d)
```

Comment: The `IndexError` is caused by this line: `matchdict[index[ind]] = match`. Let's ignore that multiprocessing issue for now, though. Can you please explain again what your `matchdictfunc` function is supposed to do? My implementation gives different results to yours.

Comment: The matchdictfunction is used to match my "real data" X and Y to my reference table (consisting of 'columns' Q and Z). But it only gives a "match" if X[i] is found in Q, AND Y[i] is found in Z at the same index as X was found in Q.
It actually works well w/o multiprocessing, it is just still a tick to slow for me. Of course I could also manually start the script with subsets of my data multiple times on different cores, but out of curiosity and learning purposes I would prefer the multiprocessing version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `matchdictfunc` currently has arguments `x`, `y`, `q`, `z` but in fact does not use them, although in the multiprocessing version it will need to use two arguments. There is also no need for function `splitinput` to replicate `Q` and `Z` into returned values `Q_split` and `Z_split`. Currently, `matchdictfunc` is expecting `Q` and `Z` to be global variables and we can arrange for that to be the case in the multiprocessing version by using the `initializer` and `initargs` arguments when constructing the pool. You should also move code that you do not need to be executed by the sub-processes into the block controlled by `if __name__ == '__main__':`, such as the arary initialization code. These changes result in:

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures

MULTIPROCESSING = True

def init_pool(q, z):
    global Q, Z
    Q = q
    Z = z

def matchdictfunc(index, X, Y):  # function to match entries of X and Y to Q and Z and get index of Q/Z where their values match X/Y
    lookup = {}
    for i, (q, z) in enumerate(zip(Q, Z)):
        lookup.setdefault((q, z), []).append(i)

    matchlist = [lookup.get((x, y), []) for x, y in zip(X, Y)]
    matchdict = {}
    for ind, match in enumerate(matchlist):
        matchdict[index[ind]] = match

    return matchdict

def split(a, n):  # function to split list in n even parts
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    return list((a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n)))

def splitinput(index, X, Y):  # split large lists X and Y in n-even parts (n = cpu_count))
    cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    #create multiple chunks for X and Y and index:
    index_split = split(index,cpu_count)
    X_split = split(X,cpu_count)
    Y_split = split(Y,cpu_count)
    return index_split, X_split ,Y_split


def main():
    # following required for non-multiprocessing
    if not MULTIPROCESSING:
        global Q, Z

    np.random.seed(1)

    # N will finally scale up to 10^9
    N = 10000000
    M = 300

    index = [str(x) for x in list(range(N))]
    X = np.random.randint(M, size=N)
    Y = np.random.randint(M, size=N)

    # Q and Z size is fixed at 120000
    Q = np.random.randint(M, size=120000)
    Z = np.random.randint(M, size=120000)

    # convert int32 arrays to str64 arrays and then to list, to represent original data (which are strings and not numbers)
    X = np.char.mod('%d', X).tolist()
    Y = np.char.mod('%d', Y).tolist()
    Q = np.char.mod('%d', Q).tolist()
    Z = np.char.mod('%d', Z).tolist()

    # for non-multiprocessing:
    if not MULTIPROCESSING:
        matchdict = matchdictfunc(index, X, Y)
    else:
        # for multiprocessing:
        # split lists to number of processors (cpu_count)
        index_split, X_split, Y_split = splitinput(index, X, Y)
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(Q, Z)) as executor:
            finallist = [result for result in executor.map(matchdictfunc, index_split, X_split, Y_split)]
            matchdict = {}
            for d in finallist:
                matchdict.update(d)

    #print(matchdict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note: I tried this for a smaller value of `N` = 1000 (printing out the results of `matchdict`) and the multiprocessing version seemed to return the same results. My machine does not have the resources to run with the full value of `N` without freezing up everything else.

**Another Approach**

I am working under the assumption that your DNA data is external and the `X` and `Y` values can be read `n` values at a time *or can be read in and written out so that this is possible.* Then rather than having all the data resident in memory and splitting it up into 32 pieces, I propose that it be read `n` values at a time and thus broken up into approximately `N/n` pieces.

In the following code I have switched to using the `imap` method from class `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`. The advantage is that it *lazily* submits tasks to the process pool, that is, the `iterable` argument doesn't have to be a list or convertible to a list. Instead the pool will iterate over the *iterable* sending tasks to the pool in `chunksize` groups. In the code below, I have used a generator function for the argument to `imap`, which will generate successive `X` and `Y` values. Your actual generator function would first open the DNA file (or files) and read in successive portions of the file.

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

def init_pool(q, z):
    global Q, Z
    Q = q
    Z = z

def matchdictfunc(t):  # function to match entries of X and Y to Q and Z and get index of Q/Z where their values match X/Y
    index, X, Y = t
    lookup = {}
    for i, (q, z) in enumerate(zip(Q, Z)):
        lookup.setdefault((q, z), []).append(i)

    matchlist = [lookup.get((x, y), []) for x, y in zip(X, Y)]
    matchdict = {}
    for ind, match in enumerate(matchlist):
        matchdict[index[ind]] = match

    return matchdict


def next_tuple(n, stop, M):
    start = 0
    while True:
        end = min(start + n, stop)
        index = [str(x) for x in list(range(start, end))]
        x = np.random.randint(M, size=n)
        y = np.random.randint(M, size=n)
        # convert int32 arrays to str64 arrays and then to list, to represent original data (which are strings and not numbers)
        x = np.char.mod('%d', x).tolist()
        y = np.char.mod('%d', y).tolist()
        yield (index, x, y)
        start = end
        if start >= stop:
            break

def compute_chunksize(XY_AT_A_TIME, N):
    n_tasks, remainder = divmod(N, XY_AT_A_TIME)
    if remainder:
        n_tasks += 1
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(n_tasks, multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 4)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize


def main():
    np.random.seed(1)

    # N will finally scale up to 10^9
    N = 10000000
    M = 300

    # Q and Z size is fixed at 120000
    Q = np.random.randint(M, size=120000)
    Z = np.random.randint(M, size=120000)

    # convert int32 arrays to str64 arrays and then to list, to represent original data (which are strings and not numbers)
    Q = np.char.mod('%d', Q).tolist()
    Z = np.char.mod('%d', Z).tolist()

    matchdict = {}
    # number of X, Y pairs at a time:
    # experiment with this, especially as N increases:
    XY_AT_A_TIME = 10000
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(XY_AT_A_TIME, N)
    #print('chunksize =', chunksize) # 32 with 8 cores
    with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(Q, Z)) as pool:
        for d in pool.imap(matchdictfunc, next_tuple(XY_AT_A_TIME, N, M), chunksize):
            matchdict.update(d)
    #print(matchdict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    t = time.time()
    main()
    print('total time =', time.time() - t)
```

**Update**

I want to eliminate using `numpy` from the benchmark. It is known that `numpy` uses multiprocessing for some of its operations and when used in multiprocessing applications can be the cause of of reduced performance. So the first thing I did was to take the OP's original program and where the code was, for example:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
X = np.random.randint(M, size=N)
X = np.char.mod('%d', X).tolist()
```

I replaced it with:

```py
import random

random.seed(1)
X = [str(random.randrange(M)) for _ in range(N)]
```

I then timed the OP's program to get the time for generating the `X`, `Y`, `Q` and `Z` lists and the total time. On my desktop the times were approximately 20 seconds and 37 seconds respectively! So in my multiprocessing version just generating the arguments for the process pool's processes is more than half the total running time. I also discovered for the second approach, that as I increased the value of `XY_AT_A_TIME` that the CPU utilization went down from 100% to around 50% but that the total elapsed time improved. I haven't quite figured out why this is.

Next I tried to emulate how the programs would function if they were reading the data in. So I wrote out 2 * `N` random integers to a file, `temp.txt` and modified the OP's program to initialize `X` and `Y` from the file and then modified my second approach's `next_tuple` function as follows:

```py
def next_tuple(n, stop, M):
    with open('temp.txt') as f:
        start = 0
        while True:
            end = min(start + n, stop)
            index = [str(x) for x in range(start, end)] # improvement
            x = [f.readline().strip() for _ in range(n)]
            y = [f.readline().strip() for _ in range(n)]
            yield (index, x, y)
            start = end
            if start >= stop:
                break
```

Again as I increased `XY_AT_A_TIME` the CPU utilization went down (best performance I found was value 400000 with CPU utilization only around 40%).

I finally rewrote my first approach trying to be more memory efficient (see below). This updated version again reads the random numbers from a file but uses generator functions for `X`, `Y` and `index` so I don't need memory for both the full lists and the splits. Again, I do not expect duplicated results for the multiprocessing and non-multiprocessing versions because of the way I am assigning the `X` and `Y` values in the two cases (a simple solution to this would have been to write the random numbers to an `X`-value file and a `Y`-value file and read the values back from the two files). But this has no effect on the running times. But again, the CPU utilization, despite using the default pool size of 8, was only 30 - 40% (it fluctuated quite a bit) and the overall running time was nearly double the non-multiprocessing running time. But why?

```py
import random
import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures
import time

MULTIPROCESSING = True

POOL_SIZE = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def init_pool(q, z):
    global Q, Z
    Q = q
    Z = z

def matchdictfunc(index, X, Y):  # function to match entries of X and Y to Q and Z and get index of Q/Z where their values match X/Y
    lookup = {}
    for i, (q, z) in enumerate(zip(Q, Z)):
        lookup.setdefault((q, z), []).append(i)

    matchlist = [lookup.get((x, y), []) for x, y in zip(X, Y)]
    matchdict = {}
    for ind, match in enumerate(matchlist):
        matchdict[index[ind]] = match

    return matchdict

def split(a):  # function to split list in POOL_SIZE even parts
    k, m = divmod(N, POOL_SIZE)
    divisions = [(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m) - (i * k + min(i, m)) for i in range(POOL_SIZE)]
    parts = []
    for division in divisions:
        part = [next(a) for _ in range(division)]
        parts.append(part)
    return parts

def splitinput(index, X, Y):  # split large lists X and Y in n-even parts (n = POOL_SIZE)
    #create multiple chunks for X and Y and index:
    index_split = split(index)
    X_split = split(X)
    Y_split = split(Y)
    return index_split, X_split ,Y_split


def main():
    global N

    # following required for non-multiprocessing
    if not MULTIPROCESSING:
        global Q, Z

    random.seed(1)

    # N will finally scale up to 10^9
    N = 10000000
    M = 300

    # Q and Z size is fixed at 120000
    Q = [str(random.randrange(M)) for _ in range(120000)]
    Z = [str(random.randrange(M)) for _ in range(120000)]

    with open('temp.txt') as f:
        # for non-multiprocessing:
        if not MULTIPROCESSING:
            index = [str(x) for x in range(N)]
            X = [f.readline().strip() for _ in range(N)]
            Y = [f.readline().strip() for _ in range(N)]
            matchdict = matchdictfunc(index, X, Y)
        else:
            # for multiprocessing:
            # split lists to number of processors (POOL_SIZE)
            # generator functions:
            index = (str(x) for x in range(N))
            X = (f.readline().strip() for _ in range(N))
            Y = (f.readline().strip() for _ in range(N))
            index_split, X_split, Y_split = splitinput(index, X, Y)
            with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(POOL_SIZE, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(Q, Z)) as executor:
                finallist = [result for result in executor.map(matchdictfunc, index_split, X_split, Y_split)]
                matchdict = {}
                for d in finallist:
                    matchdict.update(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    main()
    print('total time =', time.time() - t)
```

**Resolution?**

Can it be that the overhead of transferring the data from the main process to the subprocesses, which involves shared memory reading and writing, is what is slowing everything down? So, this final version was an attempt to eliminate this potential cause for the slowdown. On my desktop I have 8 processors. For the first approach dividing the N = 10000000 `X` and `Y` values among them means that each process should be processing `N // 8 -> 1250000` values. So I wrote out the random numbers in 16 groups of 1250000 numbers (8 groups for `X` and 8 groups for `Y`) as a binary file noting the offset and length of each of these 16 groups using the following code:

```py
import random

random.seed(1)

with open('temp.txt', 'wb') as f:
    offsets = []
    for i in range(16):
        n = [str(random.randrange(300)) for _ in range(1250000)]
        b = ','.join(n).encode('ascii')
        l = len(b)
        offsets.append((f.tell(), l))
        f.write(b)

print(offsets)
```

And from that I constructed lists `X_SPECS` and `Y_SPECS` that the worker function `matchdictfunc` could use for reading in the values `X` and `Y` itself as needed. So now instead of passing 1250000 values at a time to this worker function, we are just passing indices 0, 1, ... 7 to the worker function so it knows which group it has to read in. Shared memory access has been totally eliminated in accessing `X` and `Y` (it's still required for `Q` and `Z`) and the disk access moved to the process pool. The CPU Utilization will, of course, not be 100% because the worker function is doing I/O. But I found that while the running time has now been greatly improved, it still offered no improvement over the original non-multiprocessing version:

```
OP's original program modified to read `X` and `Y` values in from file: 26.2 seconds
Multiprocessing elapsed time: 29.2 seconds
```

In fact, when I changed the code to use multithreading by replacing the `ProcessPoolExecutor` with `ThreadPoolExecutor`, the elpased time went down almost another second demonstrating the there is very little contention for the Global Interpreter Lock within the worker function, i.e. most of the time is being spent in C-language code. The main work is done by:

```py
matchlist = [lookup.get((x, y), []) for x, y in zip(X, Y)]
```

When we do this with multiprocessing, we have multiple list comprehensions and multiple `zip` operations (on smaller lists) being performed by separate processes and we then assemble the results in the end. This is conjecture on my part, but there just may not be any performance gains to be had by taking what are already efficient operations and scaling them down across multiple processors. Or in other words, I am stumped and that was my best guess.

The final version (with some additional optimizations -- please note):

```py
import random
import concurrent.futures
import time

POOL_SIZE = 8

X_SPECS = [(0, 4541088), (4541088, 4541824), (9082912, 4540691), (13623603, 4541385), (18164988, 4541459), (22706447, 4542961), (27249408, 4541847), (31791255, 4542186)]
Y_SPECS = [(36333441, 4542101), (40875542, 4540120), (45415662, 4540802), (49956464, 4540971), (54497435, 4541427), (59038862, 4541523), (63580385, 4541571), (68121956, 4542335)]

def init_pool(q_z):
    global Q_Z
    Q_Z = q_z

def matchdictfunc(index, i):  # function to match entries of X and Y to Q and Z and get index of Q/Z where their values match X/Y
    x_offset, x_len = X_SPECS[i]
    y_offset, y_len = Y_SPECS[i]
    with open('temp.txt', 'rb') as f:
        f.seek(x_offset, 0)
        X = f.read(x_len).decode('ascii').split(',')
        f.seek(y_offset, 0)
        Y = f.read(y_len).decode('ascii').split(',')

    lookup = {}
    for i, (q, z) in enumerate(Q_Z):
        lookup.setdefault((q, z), []).append(i)

    matchlist = [lookup.get((x, y), []) for x, y in zip(X, Y)]
    matchdict = {}
    for ind, match in enumerate(matchlist):
        matchdict[index[ind]] = match

    return matchdict

def split(a):  # function to split list in POOL_SIZE even parts
    k, m = divmod(N, POOL_SIZE)
    divisions = [(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m) - (i * k + min(i, m)) for i in range(POOL_SIZE)]
    parts = []
    for division in divisions:
        part = [next(a) for _ in range(division)]
        parts.append(part)
    return parts



def main():
    global N

    random.seed(1)

    # N will finally scale up to 10^9
    N = 10000000
    M = 300

    # Q and Z size is fixed at 120000
    Q = (str(random.randrange(M)) for _ in range(120000))
    Z = (str(random.randrange(M)) for _ in range(120000))
    Q_Z = list(zip(Q, Z)) # pre-compute the `zip` function

    # for multiprocessing:
    # split lists to number of processors (POOL_SIZE)
    # generator functions:
    index = (str(x) for x in range(N))
    index_split = split(index)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(POOL_SIZE, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(Q_Z,)) as executor:
        finallist = executor.map(matchdictfunc, index_split, range(8))
        matchdict = {}
        for d in finallist:
            matchdict.update(d)

    print(len(matchdict))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    main()
    print('total time =', time.time() - t)
```

**The Cost of Inter-Process Memory Transfers**

In the code below function `create_files` was called to create 100 identical files consisting of a "pickled" list of 1,000,000 numbers. I then used a multiprocessing pool of size 8 twice to read the 100 files and unpickle the files to reconstitute the original lists. The difference between the first case (`worker1`) and the second case (`worker2`) was that in the second case the list is returned back to the caller (but not saved so that memory can be garbage collected immediately). The second case took more than three times longer than the first case. This can also explain in part why you do not see a speedup when you switch to multiprocessing.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pickle
import time

def create_files():
    l = [i for i in range(1000000)]
    # create 100 identical files:
    for file in range(1, 101):
        with open(f'pkl/test{file}.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(l, f)


def worker1(file):
    file_name = f'pkl/test{file}.pkl'
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        obj = pickle.load(f)


def worker2(file):
    file_name = f'pkl/test{file}.pkl'
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        obj = pickle.load(f)
    return file_name, obj

POOLSIZE = 8

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #create_files()

    pool = Pool(POOLSIZE)
    t = time.time()
    # no data returned:
    for file in range(1, 101):
        pool.apply_async(worker1, args=(file,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(time.time() - t)

    pool = Pool(POOLSIZE)
    t = time.time()
    for file in range(1, 101):
        pool.apply_async(worker2, args=(file,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(time.time() - t)

    t = time.time()
    for file in range(1, 101):
        worker2(file)
    print(time.time() - t)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough answer!
Both options seem to do what they are supposed to (=multiprocessing).
But somehow they both are not accelerating, but **slowing down** the whole process.
I checked time for each option on my computer:
without MP: 28s, 
Concurrent.futures with initializer: 44s, 
multiprocessing.Pool: 58s

--> However, if I reduce the size of X and Y I actually get acceleration (half size of X/Y = half the time needed for script), which tells me that in theory it should be possible to accelerate it. Memory load was high for concurrent.futures option but not to 100%.

Comment: The idea behind the **Another Approach** was that it should be considerably more memory efficient. I will have more time to look at this tomorrow.  Until then I have a few questions: When you say, "... reduce the size of X and Y", you actually mean the constant `N`, right? Also, your actual `compute_chunksize` function is not generating random numbers; it's reading in DNA data, right?. And has your `matchdictfunc` function remained unchanged?

Comment: Yes, the **Another Approach** does indeed seem much more memory efficient (nearly no change in memory usage after starting script). And yes, I meant the constant N with the reduction of size.
I guess you mean the `next_tuple` function for the random generation of numbers? So with my final data I'm reading in DNA sequences (which are basically just **N** rows of strings) and I would probably split the file up into smaller chunks and then read in one file after the other.

Comment: The output/result of the `matchdictfunc` is the same in the first approach with or without multiprocessing. But it is different in the `Another Approach`, however, I think this is due to the continuous random number generation instead of all at once. I manually checked the results and they seem to be correct (the function finds the matches in Q and Z correctly).

Comment: Yes, I meant `next_tuple`. Memory will increase even with second approach as `matchdict` fills up with returned results; but overall memory utilization should be less compared with the first approach. And depending on the size of `XY_AT_A_TIME`, you will get different results above because of how the random numbers are generated with the code as I have it.

Comment: I've added an update to the answer, for what it's worth.

Comment: Wow, really impressed by your effort, thx! I tested the multiprocessing code now on a 32-core 128gb RAM workstation with the same result --> multiprocessing still slows down compared to single core (needs about 2x as long with mp). I'm still confused why this is the case. The additional time needed for splitting the lists and starting the subprocesses is higher than the time needed to run the `matchdictfunc` itself. 
So at the moment I could split the files first and then "manually start" the script multiple times and this would yield in a faster turnover.

Comment: I've added another update to the answer. It's becoming book-length and I will soon be looking for a publisher.

Comment: Interesting! I also noticed, that worker1 takes similarly long as worker2 with Pool=1, but then only worker1 increases in speed with more Pools, while worker2 basically stays at 7-8 sec (on my computer; doesn't matter whether its 1 pool or 8 pools).

Comment: With pool size of 1, I get 6.9 and 11.8 seconds respectively. But we have totally different hardware. But if I just call `worker2` 100 times in a loop with no multiprocessing, the time is 6.7 seconds, which is better than the multiprocessing with a pool size of 8 and sort of makes my point. I will update the source for this. Change POOLSIZE = 1.